# Duplication happening when second call to warehouse item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting some strange duplication in my query the problem is I need to be able to query both stock qtys from warehouse item table and as you see i am calling it twice hence there is duplication of warehouse items. Will find that its my joins that will be the issue.

```
SELECT ki.[KitItemID]
      ,ki.[KitHeaderID]
      ,kh.StockCode as KitHeaderStockCode
      ,ki.[StockCode]
      ,ki.[StockDescription]
      ,ki.[StockItemID]
      ,ki.[Qty]
      ,ki.[IsBoard]
      ,ki.[IsSubAssembly],
      ISNULL(wip.ConfirmedQtyInStock,0) as InStockCs,
      ISNULL(SUM(wip2.ConfirmedQtyInStock), 0) as InStockWip,           
       @ppBatch as BatchID

FROM KitItem ki
LEFT JOIN KitHeader kh ON ki.KitHeaderID = kh.KitHeaderID
LEFT JOIN WarehouseItem wip2 ON ki.StockItemID = wip2.ItemID AND wip2.WarehouseID = (SELECT TOP 1 WIP_LocationID FROM Settings) 
INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseItem wip ON ki.StockItemID  =wip.ItemID INNER JOIN
dbo.Warehouse war ON wip.WarehouseID = war.WarehouseID
WHERE ki.IsBox = 0
GROUP BY 
ki.[KitItemID]
,ki.[KitHeaderID]
,kh.StockCode
,ki.[StockCode]
,ki.[StockDescription]
,ki.[StockItemID]
,ki.[Qty]
,ki.[IsBoard]
,ki.[IsSubAssembly]
,wip.ConfirmedQtyInStock
,wip2.ConfirmedQtyInStock
```

Answer (score 0):

After `ON ki.StockItemID  =wip.ItemID`, add

```
and wip.ItemID=wip2.ItemID
```

so that each row does only have data about 1 item, not 2

Comment: Sorry do you mean on the call after the inner join

Comment: yes. INNER JOIN
dbo.WarehouseItem wip ON ki.StockItemID  =wip.ItemID (ADD HERE) and ....

Comment: there still appears to be duplication it has now group them which appears to be correct.

Comment: @DavidB if you can post DDL+DML then we will have something to work on (meaning to post queries to create your table(s) and insert some sample data)

Answer (score 0):

If you get full duplicates you can use `distinct` in `select`, otherwise add a column in `group by` which is different